# SQL MAX problems in query

Tags: sql, casting, max

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? It's giving me ALL the visit dates and I'm just looking for the most recent visit date:

```
SELECT ID , MAX(CAST((CAST(VISITMO  AS nvarchar(2)) + '/' +
                      CAST(VISITDAY AS nvarchar(2)) + '/' +
                      CAST(VISITYR  AS nvarchar(4))) AS date)
                ) AS LastVisitDATE
  FROM [VisitTable] 
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE other criteria is met)

GROUP BY ID, VISITYR, VISITMO, VISITDAY
```

I kept adding to the GROUP BY statement because of the errors I got

Comment: You want the MAX date for just a particular ID in VisitTable?

Comment: Looking for the MAX visit date. Many IDs have multiple visit dates -- max visit date PER ID)

Comment: you are getting everything back because you are grouping by everything.

Comment: Yes. What's unclear is if you want the max visit date for every unique ID (many records), or if you just want the max visit date for the whole table (one record)?

Comment: I edited my query. I just want to know that Joe had his last visit date on May 2,2012 and Jan had her last visit date on Feb 3, 2004, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID , MAX(CAST((CAST(VISITMO  AS nvarchar(2)) + '/' +
                      CAST(VISITDAY AS nvarchar(2)) + '/' +
                      CAST(VISITYR  AS nvarchar(4))) AS date)
                ) AS LastVisitDATE
  FROM [VisitTable] 
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I edited above to add another query (I didn't think it mattered, but it obviously does. When I run the New query, I get back every visit date everyone has had

Comment: This worked even after I added the other query. Thanks to all of you!